# How to add clean task - Task 'clean' not found

Tags: gradle

I am using https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin and i would like to be able run task 'clean'. When i run 'gradle -d clean', it gives the following error

```
Task 'clean' not found in root project
```

To my understanding, gradle comes with task - 'clean', however the gradles-js-plugin doesn't seem to support that at this time or something. How do i add the task 'clean'?

Here is my build.gradle:

```
// Pull the plugin from Maven Central
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:1.5.0'
    }
}
// Invoke the plugin
apply plugin: 'js'

def jsSrcDir = 'public/js'

javascript.source {
    dev {
        js {
            srcDir jsSrcDir
            include "*.js"
            exclude "*.min.js"
        }
    }
    prod {
        js {
            srcDir jsSrcDir
            include "*.min.js"
        }
    }
}

combineJs{
    source = fileTree(javascript.source.dev.js.files)
    dest = file("${buildDir}/all.js")
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The clean task is introduced by the [base](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#sec:base_plugins) plugin. So you need to apply this plugin to get the clean task and the clean task rules for cleaning up specific task outputs:

```
apply plugin:'base'
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, where do you run this command? In the console?

Comment: no that statement needs to be in your build.gradle file

Comment: still not working for me. The tasks taks does not show the clean one and it fails in Jenkins with "task clean not found". Gradle version 4.6

Comment: I also tried this approach since it is the answer on many cases but it's not working for me

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are running the

```
gradle -d clean
```

command from your project home path.

Comment: Could you explain `-d` and add a reference to the official documentation?

Comment: -d stands for 
(ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html)

-d, --debug             Log in debug mode (includes normal stacktrace).

Comment: It's kinda useless to add `-d`, the default error message is very clear :D

Answer (score 3):

According to [this guideline](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/), the syntax is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id "base"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just run it from your `/android/` folder, i.e navigate to your `android` folder and run the command from there in the project dir.

you can also add

```
plugins {
    id "base"
}
```

to your gradle file

Comment: Which command ?

Comment: `gradle -d clean` this

Answer (score 0):

On android I added settings.gradle file with the a single line

```
include ':library'
```