# Android Task 'clean' not found in root project [Jenkins]

Tags: android, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build my android application.

But I'm facing below error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'clean' not found in root project 'ProjectName'.

Tried this solution but unable to solve my unable
[Stackoverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088461/how-to-add-clean-task-task-clean-not-found)

Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'     
apply plugin:'base'

android {    
        compileSdkVersion 23      
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'      
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'     
        defaultConfig {      
            applicationId "com.xyz.xxx"     
            minSdkVersion 15     
            targetSdkVersion 23    
            versionCode 12     
            versionName "1.0.2"     
            multiDexEnabled true     
        }     
        buildTypes {     
            release {     
                minifyEnabled false    
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
               'proguard-rules.pro'     
            }     
        }     
        dexOptions {     
            jumboMode true      
        }
    }     

    dependencies {     
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])      
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'      
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'         
        compile files('libs/guava-r09.jar')        
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'      
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'      
        compile project(':library')      
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'      
    }
```

Comment: can you add your gradlew build command and directory structure to your code?

Comment: Could you please let me know how I should add commands to code

Comment: Not in the code. Just seperate in your question. Just want to know if you are triggering command in correct directory